# Is there a way to add a Sharepoint Survey App to a Sharepoint List (Possibly with a flow)?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I would like to be able to add a flow to a survey that would allow it go through and approval process and update a list within SharePoint. The only options that I'm finding for the Survey app now is to export to Excel.

Comment: Probably better researched over on https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, I'm brand new on this site and I didn't realize there was a specific SharePoint site. :)